# How can I run Windows phone in Ubuntu virtually?

Tags: windows, virtualization, phone

Is it possible run Windows phone virtually in Ubuntu? If yes, how can I configure it?

I'm hoping for a step by step guide.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to create a Virtual Box VM with Windows 8 (or Win 10) on it and then install whichever version of Visual Studio you use these days to program Windows Phone.  I suspect, though, that you'll run into trouble trying to create the emulator within another Virtual Machine.